# Why qtcreator does not store my CMake command line?

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I am using qtcreator 3.2.1 with CMake. I often add or remove files to my projects (i.e. to the CMakeLists.txt files) and the standard way to have these files shown in the **Projects view** is to run CMake from the **Projects** tab: no problem so far.

My problem comes in when I actually run CMake: I always have to re-enter the CMake commad line, it seems qtcreator does not store it and it is a pain in my workflow.

Anyone having the same problem as I do? Or even better, a fix?

Thanks,

Antoine.

Comment: I assume QtCreator will use the CMakeCache file when rerunning CMake and so reentering your command line should not be necessary. You should confirm this though.

Comment: This is somehow what I was expecting as well but the command lne seems to be overwritten everytime you call it, so if you do not re-enter it you obtain the default behaviour.

Comment: Is this caused by QtCreator or the CMakeLists.txt? You can try to confirm this by building your project without QtCreator. A proper CMake project should not behave this way.

Comment: Hum, interesting, this may be linked to me using Catkin (ROS' build system which builds on top of CMake...). I'll ask on their forum. Thanks pmr ;)

Comment: Ha! That was me badly using the workflow! CMake actually work as expected. And thanks for your comments, they did help understand what was going wrong.

Comment: Can you please add this as an answer and accept it?

Comment: You want me to click the star on the left of the question? Other than that, I am not sure what you mean because you did answer me but in a comment, not in an official answer. And I cannot see any way to accept comments... Except if I missed something ;)

Comment: You can write an answer yourself and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake is actually running correctly within qtcreator. Forget about this question: things are straightforward in qtcreator and work as well as in plain CMake:
   - at the first time you run CMake you need to enter the command line
   - it is then stored into the CMakeCache
   - so the next time you run CMake you can simply click on "Run CMake" with a blank command line

Easy!

PS: thanks to pmr for showing me the right direction ;)